# "RuntimeError: Working outside of request context" in Flask when making an HTTP request

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Consider the following code trying to request for an api:

```
import requests
import os
import flask

args = {"example_args.."}

df = requests.post(
    "https://example-api.com/endpoint",
    json=args,
    headers={
        "key": os.environ["API_KEY"],
        "User-Agent": flask.request.headers.get("User-Agent", "None"),
    },
    stream=True,
)
```

I get the error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 6
      1 df = requests.post(
      2     "https://example-api.com/endpoint",
      3     json=args,
      4     headers={
      5         "key": os.environ["API_KEY"],
----> 6         "User-Agent": flask.request.headers.get("User-Agent", "None"),
      7     },
      8     stream=True,
      9 )

File c:\Users\viktorreif\Codes\ctd_codes\vorschau-backend\venv02\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py:311, in _ProxyLookup.__get__(self, instance, owner)
    308     return self
    310 try:
--> 311     obj = instance._get_current_object()
    312 except RuntimeError:
    313     if self.fallback is None:

File c:\Users\viktorreif\Codes\ctd_codes\vorschau-backend\venv02\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py:508, in LocalProxy.__init__.<locals>._get_current_object()
    506     obj = local.get()
    507 except LookupError:
--> 508     raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
    510 return get_name(obj)
...
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

The error occurs at the line with "User-Agent": flask.request.headers.get("User-Agent", user_agent).

I understand that this error is due to attempting to access flask.request outside of a request context. However, I'm not sure how to handle this correctly, especially when making an HTTP request.

How can I resolve this issue and properly set the "User-Agent" header when making an HTTP request in a Flask application?

Comment: Use some default agent ("Mozilla/...") as string literal?